# Old contained is also available(at some indices) even after copying new string to the existing string

Tags: c++, string, strcpy

I have learned that the work of `strcpy` is to copy the content of one string into another. Till now I was thinking that when we use `strcpy` then the old content is totally deleted and the new contained is copied. Kindly see the following program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char str[]="abcdef";
  strcpy(str,"xyz");
  cout<<str[4];
  cout<<str;
  return 0;
}
```

The output is `exyz`. Please visit this [online compiler](http://ideone.com/v9IPmx) to see the compiled code.

**My first problem is that, that when a new string is copied then the old contained must be deleted but this is not happening here.**

Then I concluded that since the new string length is smaller than the existing one therefore only first three contained are deleted and rest are left.
But **when I have written `cout<<str[3];` then nothing happened.**

**Why on `cout<<str[4];` we are getting `e` but on `cout<<str[3];` we are not getting `d`.**

Comment: "xyz" has a \0 at the end of it, thats why you dont see d but you see e. Its also why you should be using std::string and not C-strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'d'` is overwritten by the null terminator, so `str[3]` is just a zero. `str[4]` then contains `'e'`. `strcpy()` only modifies as many characters as it needs to, and it has no idea how long `str` is, so it cannot zero out the rest.

If you want to truly zero out the array, then use a `memset()` on it.

Comment: Sir, but when we are doing `cout<<str` then it is showing `abc`. As you said that it modifies only as many character as required then it must show `abcef`. Kindly make me understand that why on `cout<<str` it is not showing `abcef` and on `cout<<str[4]` it is showing `e`.

Comment: @Singh: `cout << str` shows only the characters prior to the first `\0` in `str[]`. You put `\0` in `str[3]`

Comment: After the strcpy, the array `str` contains `{'x', 'y', 'z', 0, 'e', 'f', 0}`. Note that the zeros are null terminators. As the others noted, printing halts at the first null terminator.